# Recompling invalid Java class in Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jar

In Oracle database we have a schema called "prodtxn" in that we load the following java classes for application purposes using

```
 host loadjava -user prodtxn/password  -verbose -resolve 
    wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
    saaj.jar
    jaxrpc.jar
    commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
    commons-discovery-0.2.jar
    axis.jar
    clickatell14.jar
```

While loading we get the message successfully loaded, but when while running the following query, we see some java class objects invalid

```
SELECT owner, object_name
FROM   dba_objects
WHERE  object_type IN ('JAVA CLASS')
AND    status != 'VALID'
```

I can see the following objects are invalid

```
/213c5fb9_AxisHTTPSessionListe
/226d1fae_CommonsHTTPSender1
/b8a75d12_CommonsHTTPSenderGzi
/90807c76_CommonsHTTPSenderMes
/78ab888e_CommonsHTTPSender
/a6c3563c_Log4JCategoryLog
/3ba8073b_Log4JLogger
/e1bfe35f_Log4jFactory
/d39d2eaa_LogKitLogger
/aee8cb05_AvalonLogger
/c072eec9_MailSender
/e8f4e62c_MailServer
/d048f0b6_MailWorker
/ca9a0853_JimiIO
/d83efe05_BSF
/f9b37edc_CastorDeserializer
/afdd6cc5_CastorSerializer
```

I tried to do the following

**SQL Prompt**

```
SQL> alter java class "/213c5fb9_AxisHTTPSessionListe" resolve;
```

Warning: Java altered with compilation errors

How can I make these objects valid?

In User_errors view i found the following

```
/213c5fb9_AxisHTTPSessionListe  JAVA CLASS  2   0   0   ORA-29521: referenced name javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent could not be found
```

Please advise.

Comment: And what compilation errors are being produced? You can check either the `loadjava` log file or the `USER_ERRORS` view.

Comment: no errors while compiling... But after that when we check invalid object in oracle schema , we get all these objects

Comment: I found the following in user_errors    ORA-29521: referenced name javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent could not be found

Comment: You should probably read through the [Database Java Developers Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chone.htm#BABCFIIF).

Comment: thanks a lot.  I able to resolve it , while loading the java using "loadjava" i used -genmissing  option , which resolved the non existences of the classes